# grid-column-end has to be one number bigger, than there are columns

Tags: css, css-grid

Given this CSS grid example:

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  background: rgba(128, 0, 0, .5);
  border: 1px solid #666;
}

.four {
  grid-area: 2/1/2/4;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Col 1</li>
  <li>Col 2</li>
  <li>Col 3</li>
  <li class="four">Col 4</li>
</ul>
```

Can anyone explain, why I do I need to set the `grid-column-end` to `4` if there are only three columns?

From what I understand from the MDN docs, the grid-area should be `grid-area: 2/1/2/3;` – but that would result in the `li.four` only spanning two columns.

To me this seems like a strange bug, because I need to span column 1-4 to actually have a visual span of a row over three columns.

Comment: 3 columns --> 4 lines around the columns

Comment: Grid values are based on the number of vertical/horizontal lines between/around the cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone explain, why I do I need to set the `grid-column-end` to 4 if there are only three columns?

`grid-column-end`, along with its other related properties, target column lines, not tracks.

Therefore, `grid-column-end: 4` is targeting the fourth column line, which is the right-side border (in LTR) of the third column.

[image]
<sup>Firefox Dev Tools (background color changed for demo purposes)</sup>

> From what I understand from the MDN docs, the `grid-area` should be `grid-area: 2/1/2/3` – but that would result in the `li.four` only spanning two columns.

As you can see, `grid-column-end: 3` is the right-side border of the second column.

And `grid-row-end` should be `3` (not `2`). The layout works anyway because, since the start and end lines are both 2 (creating no track), the end value is invalid and falls back to the default, [which is a span of 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#common-uses-numeric).

These properties – `grid-row-start`, `grid-column-start`, `grid-row-end`, and `grid-column-end` – are referred to in the spec as **[line-based placement](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#line-placement)**.